# Updating AFP version on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, mac, file-sharing, afp

We have a couple of Macs, running Leopard and Snow Leopard in our otherwise pure Windows environment.

We cannot get file names longer than 31 characters and some times the file permissions gets scrabbled (users can't delete their own folders or access files they usually access). This only occurs when connecting through AFP, We've tried with SMB but it's horribly slow when working with larger documents, so it's not an option.

I somewhere read about AFP 3.0 being the answer. So my question is:

**Is there some way of updating my "AFP version" on Windows Server 2003, or does anyone have a different idea of what might help to resolve this situation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Microsoft is never going to bring their Services for Mac implementation up to date, so you'll have to replace it with something better.  I haven't used it myself, but [ExtremeZ-IP](http://www.grouplogic.com/products/extremeZ-IP/) is the one I've seen recommended.

Comment: thanks, I'll have a look at it. Do you know if Server 2008 is more compatible with AFP and file sharing for mac?

Comment: @Niclas: Actually, Microsoft dropped AFP support entirely in Server 2008 ([1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756977.aspx), [2](http://www.zdnet.co.uk/blogs/the-open-source-revolution-10014902/windows-server-2008-drops-the-ball-for-mac-compatibility-10017735/)), so I'm going to have to say no.

Comment: Say WHAT!? I cant connect using AFP at all? My colleagues are going to kill me when we do the switch.. :)